# Proving $\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{a+b+2c} \le \frac{1}{4}(a+b+c)$ for positive real $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $$\frac{ab}{a+b+2c} + \frac{bc}{b+c+2a} + \frac{ca}{c+a+2b} \le \frac{1}{4}(a+b+c)$$
for positive real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: thoughts? How did you approach this question?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **Possible Typo**: Perhaps $$\cdots + \frac{bc}{\color{red}{a}+c+2a}+ \cdots$$ should be $$\cdots + \frac{bc}{\color{red}{b}+c+2a}+ \cdots .$$

Comment: @AnotherUser, thanks for the suggestion. I am still a high school student so I have little to no knowledge about Mathematics, apologies for not being able to approach this problem. I did try making some substitutions to try getting a value less than a fourth, but that's probably not the way to solve problems like these.

Answer (score 3):

By AM-HM
$$\sum_{sym} \frac{bc}{2a+b+c} \leq \sum_{sym} \frac{bc}{4}(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c})=\frac{a+b+c}{4}.$$
Seems like you are new to inequalities. To study this topic, I recommend you [this book](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Inequalities%20A%20Mathematical%20Olympiad%20Approach%20-%20Manfrino,%20Ortega,%20and%20Delgado%20(Birkhauser,%202009).pdf).